# Python, kivy, проблема с модулем

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

я новичок в програмировании, решил попробовать kivy. У меня возникает такая ошибка

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\verto\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-02-29_4.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.18
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.10
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.23
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\verto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\verto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\verto\Documents\Python_test\Test_fils\Test_yvik.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.ladel import Label
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.uix.ladel'
```

Мой код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.ladel import Label


class FirstKivy(App):
    def build(self):

        return Label(text='Hello kivy!')

FirstKivy().Run()
```

имя файла Test_yvik.py
версия питона: 3.7.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class FirstKivy(App):
    def build(self):

        return Label(text='Hello kivy!')

FirstKivy().run()
```